# Unable to create hierarchy in PivotTable

Tags: pivot-table, qlikview

This is how my dataset looks like:

```
ItemType       ItemCategory         ItemName
ItemType1      ItemCat1             Item1
ItemType1      ItemCat1             Item2
ItemType1      ItemCat2             Item3
ItemType2      ItemCat1             Item4
ItemType2      ItemCat2             Item5
ItemType2      ItemCat2             Item6
ItemType3      ItemCat1             Item7
ItemType3      ItemCat2             Item8
ItemType3      ItemCat1             Item9
```

I am trying to display this in PivotTable so that i can get tree view kind of structure with ItemCategory as Row rather than column.

```
ItemType       ItemCat1       ItemCat2
ItemType1      Item1          Item3
               Item2

ItemType2      Item4          Item5
                              Item6

ItemType3      Item7          Item9
               Item8
```

To achieve this, this is what i did.

I created ItemType and ItemCategory as Dimensions and ItemName as Expression. But it does not show me the data in the ItemName column.

I created ItemType, ItemCategory and ItemName as Dimensions, but it does not let me drag and drop ItemCategory column on top of ItemName. It however shows the data.

I created ItemType, ItemCategory and ItemName as Dimensions and ItemName as Expression, it allows me to drag and drop the ItemCategory on top of ItemName expression column but the result is not what i am looking for.

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I think I was able to achieve what you intended.

Solution used :

- ItemType and ItemCategory as Dimensions.
- ItemName used in a Expression, Concat(ItemName, chr(13))
- In the Presentation tab of the Pivot Table properties, tick the Wrap Cell Text check box in order to display multiple lines in a cell.

The trick here is the Concat function. Since you have multiple ItemName for the same ItemCategory and ItemType you need some way of putting them together. Concat does it, usually generating a comma separated string (you could do it also here, with Concat(ItemName, ',')).

It also might be a good a idea to use the expression Concat(DISTINCT ItemName, chr(13)) to ensure that you don't have repeated ItemNames in the same cell.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I do not want Concat item names. I want them to be displayed in separate row.